# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement. If update with Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

On run, gives error

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Code:

```
 update CheckInCheckOut 
 set CountHours = (select ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,CheckIn,CheckOut) / 60.0 / 60.0), 2))  
 where UserId_Fk = 3
```

This query works when I write it as:

```
update CheckInCheckOut 
set CountHours = ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, '2014-05-15 00:23:04.580', '2014-05-15 00:25:04.580')  / 60.0 / 60.0), 2)

   CheckIn datetime,
  CheckOut datetime
```

Example would be appreciated.

Comment: I've edited in question

Comment: OK, but next time, please add this to the **tags**! `sql-server-2008` That's what they're there for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declare a variable for the purpose:

```
DECLARE @Result Decimal(18, 0)
SET @Result = ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,'2014-05-15 00:23:04.580','2014-05-15 00:25:04.580') / 60.0 / 60.0), 2)

update CheckInCheckOut 
set CountHours= @Result
where UserId_Fk=3
```

Comment: sorry.. I want to use CheckIn and CheckOut instead of '2014-05-15 00:23:04.580' and '2014-05-15 00:25:04.580'.
'Invalid column name CheckIn, CheckOut'

Comment: then you have to specify `From` for select statement.