# Update Temp Table with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting this error

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

My `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE #Results
SET CustomerName = dbo.GetCustomerNameByCustomerId(CustomerId),
    TotalIncremental = Sum(IncrementalDollarsDebitCredit),
    TotalDeficiency = 0
FROM 
    IncrementalCreditHeader ICH
INNER JOIN 
    IncrementalCreditHistory IC ON IC.IncrementalCreditID = ICH.IncrementalCreditID
WHERE
    IC.BillingPeriodStartDate < = '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND ICH.ARCreatedFlag = 'Y' AND ICH.ActiveFlag = 1
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use GROUP BY?

Comment: You should have #Results in your update query. Be careful of those scalar functions, they can seriously hinder performance. Especially something as simple as that one sounds. It seems like maybe you are using a scalar function instead of just adding another join to your query.

Comment: for update group by doesn't work...how can i change this query to suffic the result set

Comment: Could you just run the update and then in a third statement run a `SELECT * FROM #Results GROUP BY CustomerID`? That would avoid using the Group By in the update...

Comment: I dont have customer id in temp table...i dont want to use customer id, since i am using this temp table to update other few places

Comment: see [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23672455/3854195) on using variables

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any link between #results and the other tables. Are you trying to update same number to all the rows, from all the rows in the other tables?

Answer (score 0):

in general, you can use the fact that you can update [`common table expressions`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL server + apply the window function, like this:

```
create table temp (client_id int, amount int, total_amount int)

insert into temp (client_id, amount)
select 1, 10 union all
select 1, 15 union all
select 2, 5 union all
select 2, 7 union all
select 2, 15

;with cte as (
    select total_amount, sum(amount) over(partition by client_id) as new_total_amount
    from temp
)
update cte set
    total_amount = new_total_amount

--------------------------------
client_id   amount  total_amount
        1       10            25
        1       15            25
        2        5            27
        2        7            27
        2       15            27
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca845/1)</kbd>**

But in your question, you have to add `#Results` table to your update query otherwise it's not clear for SQL Server which rows to update